# Select all li's but not children

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$li = $("li", this)
```

Which is selecting all of the `li`'s in my code. This works fine however I want `$li` to exclude the `li`'s that are within a submenu.

```
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">blah 1</a></li>
        <ul id="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">blah 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blah 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blah 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blah 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

So `$li` would only reference the blah's not the sub's.

I thought it was something like:

```
$li = $("li", this).parents()
```

But this doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use the child selector `>`:

```
$("#navigation > li")
```

Answer (score 14):

You want to use the immediate child selector, `>`:

```
$li = $('#navigation > li');
```

Comment: @David: look at our timestamps - exactly the same second :-)

Comment: @Andy: Awesome. +1 for you, then.

Answer (score 5):

```
var li = $("#navigation > li");
```

The `>` selects only direct children

Answer (score 0):

Future Googlers may find this answer useful if they are here (like me) looking for **Select all li's without any children**

```
$("#mylist li:not(:has(ul))")
```

or

```
$("#mylist li:not(:has(li))")
```