# count direct children in html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-lists, markup

Here's how the HTML markup looks like

```
<ul>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>green</li>
  <li>
  <ul>
       <li>banana</li>
       <li>pineapple</li>
       <li>peanut</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>
  <ul>
       <li>sun</li>
       <li>mars</li>
       <li>earth</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>orange</li>
</ul>
```

how do I count direct children (`<li>`) in this list? (items containing red,green,blue,orange) ?

Comment: First, before asking this question, **correct your HTML**. A `ul` is ***not*** a valid child of another `ul` element. Wrap the child `ul` elements in `li` elements (which are the *only* valid children of a `ul` or `ol`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all li's but not children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432705/select-all-lis-but-not-children) -- please use the search before you ask a new question. See also [How can I count the number of children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul > li').length;
```

`'ul > li'` selector point only first level of children i.e direct children for all ul.

or

```
$('ul').children().length;
```

If  your code is string variable like

```
var html = '<ul><li>.....';
```

Then

```
$('ul > li', $(html)).length;
```

#### NOTE: Above code will find all li

To find only first level of `li` use:

```
$('ul:not(li > ul)').children().length;
```

You can also use:

```
$('ul:not(li > ul) > li').length
```

For html variable string:

```
$(html).children('ul > li').length;
```

Comment: The outer UL is anonymous, you code will find all the LIs who's parent is UL.

Comment: I think your answer needs more examples, but +1 anyways

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("ul > li").length
```

Other way:

```
$("ul").children().length
```

In JQuery documentation you can also find [`size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method to get the number of elements. However, it is better to use `length`, since it is simply faster.

The first `ul` element can be taken by `:first` selector. Another way is to set the concrete `<ul>` element ID, and address it with `#element_id` selector.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xDYn9/

Comment: The outer UL is anonymous, you code will find all the LIs who's parent is UL.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var count = 0;
for (var ch = ul.firstChild; ch; ch = ch.nextSibling)
  if (ch instanceof HTMLLIElement) count++;
```

Comment: 1) There is no method `querySelctor`, you are missing a letter. 2) It is not supported by many browsers. 3) There is `HTMLLIElement`.

Comment: corrected typos in 1 and 3. to 2, how many? you mean IE6 and IE7, you may replace it with `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]`.

Comment: Yes. And it is faster. Moreover, what, do you think, child elements should be in `ul` element by the standard except `li`? Why do you need `instanceof` checking? Anyway, my idea is so that you should not downvote until you 1) are not absolutely sure that other variant is not a valid answer for the question, 2) are not sure that you know more than others. Of course, both things should be totally proven. If you have an idea of how to update another answer, there is the comments section under each node.

Comment: There are **TextNode**s so you have to test with instanceof. Second querySelector faster, try jsperf for that. Third your code is wrong (even now), so I downvoted an easy answer without carefully consider the question.